# Conceptos de base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos

Por ejemplo estoy haciendo este esquema [image: ejemplo] ¿Como sabes que es (1,1) ó (1,n) ? No entiendo como puedes sacar las relaciones. Mas o menos la teoría la entiendo. Pero si yo me encontrará un esquema así no seria capaz de sacar las cardinalidad.

Comment: 1 departamento puede tener varias personas ?  si? pues (1,n). Puede una persona trabajar en varios departamentos? si? pues (n,n). En tu grafico ves que 1 departamento contiene varias personas pero una persona no puede estar en mas de un departamento

Comment: ¿Pero las relaciones se ponen al revés?

Comment: ¿Al revés por qué? Bpico, tienes reputacion suficiente como para entrar en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)? ahi se puede discutir mejor el tema

Comment: Si, en un momento lo debatimos. Muchas gracias, no sabia de la existencia de chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

la notación de `{?,?}` indica cuantos entidades pueden existir al lado de una relación, así determinan cuantos conexiones hay entre dos tipos de elementos.
Siguiendo la conexión, tu lees el valor que apunta al otro elemento y sabes cuantas conexiones son posibles.

Concreto en tu ejemplo eso significa:

- `{1,n}` En un `departamento` *trabajan* por lo menos 1, pero hasta n `empleados`
- `{1,1}` Un `Empleado` puede *trabajar* para exactamente *un* departamento

En el esquema también esta definido como identificar los entidades:

- Un departamento esta definido por su clave única de **numdpto**
- Un empleado esta definido por su clave unica de **numemp**
- Un empleado tiene una clave externa **numdpto** que apunta al su departamento